# Getting cash from ATM at MEX airport

Tags: atms, mex

I'm heading to Mexico from the USA soon and I'm wondering about getting cash (pesos) when I arrive at MEX.

From a map of the terminal I've seen (terminal 1), it does seem like there are several ATMs.

This leads to my two part question:

1. Is it pretty much guaranteed that I will be able to get cash from an ATM in the terminal? I'll be arriving midday on a Friday and I'll be using my bank's debit card. I know my card will work in general. I'm asking more about general availability of working ATMs with available cash. This will save me the need to get pesos in the USA before my trip (which a much worse exchange rate).
2. Is there any worry about a given ATM being fake? I've seen advice about only using ATMs that are part of a bank. Any appropriate advice for ATMs at MEX airport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did this a couple weeks ago.

As [the airport map](https://www.aicm.com.mx/en/interactive-map) shows, there are a ton of ATMs in terminal 1 as you come out of customs, from many different banks. Each of them may charge a slightly different fee, but I had absolutely no trouble finding a working one. You have a lot of options.

The ATMs in the airport terminal are all quite official looking, built into designated areas with signs displaying the bank's name ([like this](https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/mexico-city-airport-citibanamex-atm-and-immigration-sign-picture-id982730468)), so it's unlikely one of those will be fake. It never hurts to [be on the lookout for card skimmers](https://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/gas-pump-atm-skimmers.php), which is a problem in Mexico and the US, and if a particular ATM does seem suspicious, there are lots more to choose from in the airport.

There are also many currency exchange booths present. In the worst-case scenario where you're somehow unable to use an ATM at all for some reason, you could change some USD to Pesos (the rate will be bad, but it works in an emergency) to get you through a short time or take Uber into the city, which you can pay for with your phone.

Enjoy your trip!